# python check user input for email password loop

Tags: python, smtplib, password-checker

I would like to have my script verify that an email password is correct before proceeding with the rest of the script. I'm sure it's just a simple loop, but I can't think of an easy way to do it. Right now my script is:

```
import arcpy, os, sys, time, subprocess, collections, datetime, smtplib
from datetime import datetime
print("This script will check your email password to verify it is  correct.")
usr = "your_email@gmail.com"
print("Please enter the password for " + usr + ":")
psw = raw_input()


def passwordcheck(usr,psw):
    server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(usr,psw)
    server.quit()
    print("Thank you. Password was correct.")


try:
    passwordcheck(usr,psw)

except:
    print("Password was incorrect.")
```

I'd like a simple loop to allow the user 3 attempts at entering the correct password, and then if no correct password was entered, kill the script.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to check and see if the `server.login()` fails or not? Because you're not sue of the users *actual* password beforehand? If so, catching `server.login()` in the `try` would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would make much more sense.

```
def passwordcheck(usr,psw):
    server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    try:
        server.login(usr,psw)
        ret = True
    except:
        ret = False
    server.quit()
    return ret

for i in range(3):
    psw = raw_input("Please enter the password for " + usr + ": ")
    if passwordcheck(usr,psw) is False:
        print("Password was incorrect.")
    else:
        print("Thank you. Password was correct.")
        break
```

Because handling the error closer to the error source and acting accordingly should (is?) considered best practice.
Also, considering you kept `Password was incorrect` outside of the function call you should probably keep the positive output close as well (always keep similar outputs close to each other).

So handle the error in `passwordcheck` and deal with the return code of the function istead.
This is probably not a typical question for SO since there's nothing wrong with your initial code there for this is more a code review come to think of it.

Comment: Yours post is a suggestion, (and a good one), but not an answer.

Comment: @zondo Completely missed the one-liner stating he wanted 3 tries per go.

Comment: Where is this example would I ask for the password to be entered?

Comment: @morganrohan-smith sorry, completely forgot to add that line. On a train and the text is bouncing around like crazy haha. Its no excuse to write crappy answered but I hope you can understand my slip-up. The code should now ask for every iteration to enter a password.

Comment: @Torxed perfect! Thank you very much. I added:    if passwordcheck(usr,psw) is False: exit()          to kill the script if the password was incorrect, before it was just continuing, and would have crashed later when sending a different email later on

Comment: With Gmail, it will result in an error either way if Less Secure Apps aren't enabled.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it:

```
def passwordcheck(usr)
    print("This script will check your email password to verify it is  correct.")
    usr = "your_email@gmail.com"
    for i in range(3):
        print("Please enter the password for " + usr + ":")
        psw = raw_input()
        try:
            server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
            server.starttls()
            server.login(usr,psw)
            server.quit()
            print "Thank you. Password was correct."
            break
        except:
            if i < 3:
                print "Password was incorrect. Try again:"
                continue
        print "Password was incorrect. 3 times"
        break
```

Comment: That should be `i < 2` ... `i` will only be `0, 1, 2`.

Comment: I modified it just a bit, but that works exactly how I was hoping. Thank you very much.